# Portfolio optimization problem: $minimize \ V(w) \ subject \ to \ R(w)=\mu, \sum_{i=1}^n w_i = a$

Tags: optimization, finance

A porfolio $w=(w_1,...,w_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

The expected return of the porfolio is:
$R(w)=E(\sum_{i=1}^n w_iX_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n w_ir_i$

The variance $V(w)=w^\top\Sigma w$

Optimization problem: $minimize \ V(w) \ subject \ to \ R(w)=\mu, \sum_{i=1}^n w_i = a$

The text book mention that the unique solution is $w^*=\sum^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}| & | \\
\mathbb{1}&r\\
|&|
\end{pmatrix}
A^{-1} 
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
\mu
\end{pmatrix}$,

where $A=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{1}^\top \Sigma^{-1} \mathbb{1}& \mathbb{1}^\top \Sigma^{-1} r\\
\mathbb{1}^\top \Sigma^{-1} r & r^\top \Sigma^{-1} r
\end{pmatrix} $, whhich is invertible. Assume $r \notin Span(1), \mathbb{1}$ denotes the all-ones vector in dimension $n$

How to show $A$ is invertible and how to derive the unique solution $w^*$

Comment: What is the determinant of $A$? The KKT conditions answer the second part of your question

Comment: $\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}\newcommand{\y}{\mathbf{y}}$To help with showing that $A$ is invertible, remember that if $M$ is a real symmetric positive definite matrix then $\langle \x, \y\rangle_M := \x^T M\y$ is an inner product, and satisfies the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ($\left(\x^T M\y\right)^2 \le \left( \x^T M\x\right)\left(\y^T M\y\right)$ for all vectors $\x, \y$).